# NodeJS diffrence between express() and express.Router() in sub routes

Tags: node.js, express

I create a sub route in my server like `'/users'` and it uses `userRoute = express.Router()`

But in express document in [mountpath](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.mountpath) part it use another way like a use `userRoute = express()` for sub route and call it sub app here it is:

```
var app = express(); // the main app
var admin = express(); // the sub app
...
app.use('/admin', admin); // mount the sub app
```

What are their difference and usage?

Comment: An `app` is a router, but it also has lots more functionality such as `.locals`, it's own template rendering configuration, it's own application settings, etc....  Use a router, if you just want a router.  Use a sub-app if you want a whole separate app configuration that just happens to share part of the top level of the path.

Comment: As I get when I use an `app` I can set specific theme engine or ... for my route. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You always need to use `express()` to create the top-level server app, but to create sub-apps containing isolated blocks of routes or other functionality you can choose between mounting a new `express()` app, or an `express.Router()` Router.

The difference between these is in the amount of specific functionality provided to that block; Routers are simpler and focus mainly only on routing, and may be enough in many cases where you just want to logically organise your application. If you look at the the documented properties, methods & events available to both the Application and Router objects, you see that Application has all the ones that Router does, with additional ones that can be grouped into four main areas of functionality:

1. App settings (`get()`, `set()`, `disable()`, `disabled()`, `enable()`, `enabled()`)
2. Templating (`engine()`, `render()`, `locals`)
3. The ability to be notified on being mounted by a parent app (the `mount` event)
4. Access to the path it is mounted at (`mountpath`, `path()`)

So if you don't need to use any of these, or in some cases do but don't need them to be isolated from the parent app, then you can use a Router.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146164/nodejs-diffrence-between-express-and-express-router-in-sub-routes?noredirect=1#comment69499596_41146164) when I use an `app` instead of `router` I can set specific theme engine or ... for my route.